# React - use props with separate files to avoid hardcoding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties

I am new to React. In my Homepage component I want to avoid hardcoding "Hello World" inside my PageHeader by using props. I am trying to declare my prop, title, inside another file, App.js, inside my render function but nothing is showing up. How do I use React efficiently to use props with separate files to avoid hardcoding? What is the best way to do this?

My App.js file:

```
class App extends Component {

render() {  
    return (  

      <div className="App">

          <Homepage title="Hello World" />

      </div>

);
  }
}

export default App;
```

My Homepage.js file:

```
const Homepage = (props) => {

return (

    <div>

        <PageHeader> {props.title} </PageHeader>

    </div>
)
}

export default Homepage;
```

Also, my files are imported correctly.

Note: I am importing PageHeader from React-Bootstrap so when I try to do the answer below it says that it's a duplicate declaration. How can I change my code to avoid this?

Comment: Why .js vs .jsx for the extension if you're using JSX in the code? React doesn't like this much. Anyways - put a `debugger` right before the return statement for your `Homepage` and check what `props` is, that'll give you a clue of what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the props to the child elements explcitly. you could use {...props} as an attribute on the component / use react's props.children to display the content that is been passed within the tags body.

Here are the couple of ways to acheive what you asked for.

Passing props to the children component:

```js
const PageHeader = ReactBootstrap.PageHeader;
const Homepage = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <PageHeader> {props.title} </PageHeader>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Homepage title="Hello World - 1" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.29.4/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I am importing PageHeader from React-Bootstrap so when I try to do the answer below it says that it's a duplicate declaration. How can I change my code to avoid this?

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. I didnt realize that PageHeader is from react bootstrap. All you are missing is the ReactDOM.render in your code.

Comment: This doesn't work for me because my Homepage and App are in different files. Note that I have ReactDOM.render in my index.js file and inside my render is Router and document.getElementById('root'). I already imported PageHeader from React Bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer to your question may be handled by Javascript instead, please take a look at this post: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-structure-your-project-and-manage-static-resources-in-react-native-6f4cfc947d92

You can review how they manage hardcoded text using a separated file and then importing it into your js files

```
const strings = {
  onboarding: {
    welcome: {
      heading: 'Welcome',
      text1: "What you don't know is what you haven't learn",
      text2: 'Visit my GitHub at https://github.com/onmyway133',
      button: 'Log in'
    },
    term: {
      heading: 'Terms and conditions',
      button: 'Read'
    }
  }
}
export default strings
```

You need to place that file into a 'res' folder and then you can import it into any JS file using the res folder relative path:

```
import strings from '../res/strings'
```